# When I Try to build the project in Android Studio - kotlin , I'm unable to exactly find the error is even though I have updated to latest version

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle

I am unable to build and run the projects as I'm forced to solve the error first before building eventually leading me to this error.

*Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.*

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYbvL.png)

although there are errorS, the result comes with success note - [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDGvB.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3WpO.png)

Answer (score 1):

So the issue was with the Gradle Scripts -> build.gradle(Module:app) -> open this file
[A snip of the screen of the build.gradle file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yib5L.png)

And then update the dependencies, the way to do that is by hovering over the mouse to the highlighted code segment, then you'll be directed with a suggestion to change, then change and Sync the gradle file, I hope it works for since it did for me.

Try following the 1min vedio if you have further issues.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NCzi0_I05yY